# Should we burninate the [question-answering] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Currently, the [question-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question-answering) tag has 172 questions and 56 followers. The tag is about

> the computer task of mechanically answering questions posed in natural language.

The tag is misused as most of the questions tagged with it are completely unrelated to the tag info, but are questions tagged by someone who has a question and needs an answer. This is pointless, since this is already what Stack Overflow is about.

This is not really a [burninate-request], I just want to start a discussion about the tag as it needs at least a cleanup.

Comment: Let's put an end to [question-answering]!

Comment: I am not a matter expert, so not posting an answer, but after going over the questions there are some which actually follow its guidance. I would suggest to rename it to something like `qa-model` or `qa-task` (again, experts should probably nail the best one) to emphasize its true meaning and (hopefully) avoid misuse

Comment: Can one really be an expert on answering questions on question answering?

Comment: This tag isn't even a programming concept. Why we keep it? Who's the target audience of questions tagged with this?

Comment: I didn't have any "New Year's Resolution" for 2021, but I quite like this Tag, so now I have "one"... => Wait for the next SME in THE Tag...!

Comment: @Braiam The tag is supposed to be about [question answering in natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering), so it's a fairly important programming concept.

Comment: I find the Tag Description a bit vague, and prone to be easily "misused" ... => Maybe make it another Synonym for the [tag:natural-language] Tag which is already a Synonym for the [tag:nlp] Tag (17,000 Qt's) which is actually also already used for a few of the Qt's in the Tag...

Comment: ... But it (the `question-answering` Tag) should NOT be suggested by "the System" or the (Advanced) Users following/answering the `nlp` Tag (15k+ Followers) will get "annoyed" when it gets wrongly selected...

Comment: Or make it selectable ONLY if the `nlp` Tag has already been selected, then it adds some "Value" to the `nlp` Tag in a Qt...

Comment: Or like @Tomerikoo suggested, rename it to stg like `nlp-qa` maybe (doesn;t exist)..., with a clear and unambiguous Tag Description...

Comment: @AndersonGreen "important" really? Important for me is what library I'm using for the practical programming question I have, no generic conceptual stuff. Tags are supposed to be well defined categories. This is not a well defined category. The "concept" is even the interception between two different things.

Comment: I would suggest `nlp-question-answering` due to the ease of mistaking anything `qa` with Quality Assurance.

Comment: As @AdamBurke says QA is "Quality Assurance" (or occasionally "Quantitative Analysis"). I'd suggest `nlp-question-answer`, rather than `answering` because it's shorter and sounds more like a subject, rather than just wanting a question to be answered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comments have pointed out that the concept the tag was supposed to be about *is* a real topic for programming.  The tag name is a massive problem, but we can fix that with a **rename rather than deletion**.

[Adam Burke suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409210/should-we-burninate-the-question-answering-tag?cb=1#comment855242_409210) `[nlp-question-answering]` - NLP = Natural Language Processing. (qa-something has a name collision with the QA = Quality Assurance common abbreviation, so avoid that.)

A further [refinement of that idea by rjmunro](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409210/should-we-burninate-the-question-answering-tag?cb=1#comment855303_409210), `[nlp-question-answer]` might help discourage use by people who "want their question answered", although I don't think it helps much in that respect. It is shorter.

We might not need a specific tag for this at all, but [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) alone is a pretty big tag, with over 17k questions.  An upvote for this answer is a vote for renaming [question-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question-answering) to something non-terrible.  A downvote for this answer is a vote for anything other than that (probably burnination).